# HTML / CSS: exception in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, web

sorry if the question title is weak, i can't quite sum my problem up into one snappy tagline...

I'm working on a website (using Joomla) and i've had to insert a DIV serving as a **sidebar** on the right side of the page. in order for it to be displayed "above" (or "over", i mean on the z-axis) the regular page content, i'm using a negative margin on the left side of it, covering the whole width of it, so it will simply float to the right and sit there, which **works fine in ff and IE**.

Since i've rarely ever run into issues with Chrome that were fine in IE, i didn't bother to check until quite late:

Now i see that in Chrome, the **div is just sitting below** (at the bottom of) **the regular content**; despite the "inline" display-types and the negative margin.
Now I've tried ridiculous things to make it work, but for some reason it just won't.

Can someone tell me how i can get it to work in Chrome?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cframe">
      <div class="content">
          ...
      </div>
      <div class="sideright">
          ...
      </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.cframe {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: top;
}
div.content {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 751px;
    padding: 60px;
}
DIV.sideright {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 320px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -200px;
}
```

...this is what i'm stuck with right now, it's all quite ugly.

[link to live-page removed as the solution has already been applied]

(The sidebar is the div classed `sideright`, and contains a module titled `Archiv`)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the div.content css to:

```
div.content {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using float, but then setting the position to relative. You should remove the relative part of your css for the siderright and it should fix the issue

Edit: even better you should change the position to absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Set your container div to position:relative and then position:absolute your sidebar in relation to that.

```
.cframe {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}

.sideright {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 320px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the answers above but I take their word that they worked. However, your question caught my eye, because I thought you were looking for a browser hack.

There are ways that you can tell an element to behave differently on a specific browser. This happens sometimes across browsers and the best way is to hack each individual browser and give them specific instructions. For chrome, of course you'll have to use a webkit.

This would be an easy example of the syntax to follow:

```
<p>TEST</p>


p {color:green;}
   @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
       p {color:red;}
}
```

Try the [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/KJA4S/4/) in several browsers and notice how only chrome will display it in red

Comment: thank you, but as you realized i was looking for a general solution.

When it comes to browser hacks, i prefer JS to get the user agent (although i hear that is in bad taste), it seems to be WAY more reliable than those kinds of browser hacks when it comes to cross-version compatibility. Is there an actual downside to that?

Comment: css is far more reliable than JS and lighter as well. I build as much as possible in css, and use JS as a support system for those operations in which the logic or algorithm goes outside the scope of abilities for css. But many developers feel comfortable with JS as the main core. I instruct all my developers to use css mostly

Comment: p.s. I understand you have your answer already and that's great. I thought you'd like to know you could use a hack as well\